# Is the EAVCleaner Extension safe to Use on my Magento installation?

Tags: eav, database-update, entities

Project GitHub Repository: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner

Has anyone used these cleaners before? I think this application is excactly what we need, but I am unsure how to know for certain that it is safe to run against my system's database. Has anyone had experience with this with a lot of data? 250k SKU with 5+ stores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should of course check this on a dev shop before. At the time of writing, there are two important open pull requests you should merge yourself if not already done: [#19](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner/pull/19) & [#20](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner/pull/20).

You can easily check the commands with the `--dry-run` option. E.g.:

```
n98-magerun.phar eav:check:models --dry-run
```

You may also want to check out the [cleaning script of Atwix](https://www.atwix.com/magento/removing-needless-product-attribute-values/).

Comment: Cleaning Script just gives PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: Dry run seems good, but having an 'invalid method...error when trying to run. Updating to the latest release right now to see if it helps.

Comment: This is fixed in the mentioned pull requests, which are now merged.

Comment: Seems to run, but I'm burning over 4 GB of memory so it keeps failing.(Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted)... Do you know of a way to do this by ID?

Comment: Working on a new script, but answer is still right. Thanks on letting me know about the #19 and #20 updates as that made the difference even before the memory issue.

Comment: We successful where able to update this plugin to clean the eav. Worked great, however, if you are using by default, make sure no other services are running. We had to use almost 64 GB of RAM...so safe to use is where I'm getting at.